# SPFX Application Customizer - Unable to add Component

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I am trying to use component in SPFX Extention.
Followed steps mentioned in the below link.
https://nanddeepnachanblogs.com/posts/2019-04-09-using-react-components-in-spfx-extension-application-customizer/
But i am getting below error.
Failed to create application customizer 'ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer.

Adding below line also not working.
const test =React.createElement("div",null,null)

SPFX version:1.16.1
React:17.0.2

Please help.